# Independence of Poisson processes having rates depending on the sample path

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I am trying to prove an equality and through my computation I have to compute $Var \left[\sum_{j=1}^{J} \mathcal{Y}_{j} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} a_j(\mathbf{X}(t_k)) (t_{k+1}-t_k) \right) \right]$ where $\mathcal{Y}_{j}$ are independent unit poisson processes, $\mathbf{X}$ is a sample patha and $a_j$ are scalar functionals of the sample path. Using independence, can we claim that 
$$Var \left[\sum_{j=1}^{J} \mathcal{Y}_{j} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} a_j(\mathbf{X}(t_k)) (t_{k+1}-t_k) \right) \right]= \sum_{j=1}^{J} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} a_j(\mathbf{X}(t_k)) (t_{k+1}-t_k) $$
Or this is not true since the rates depndens on the same sample path?? I have the same issue when dealing with the covariance!!!  If it is not true, there is any hint to deal with path dependence.

Comment: This is obviously not true: the left side is a constant, while the right side is random.

Comment: Could you clarify what the process $\mathbf{X}$ is?

Comment: The process $\mathbf{X}$ is given by                                                $$\mathbf{X} (t_{k}) = \mathbf{x}_{0}+\sum_{j=1}^{J} \mathcal{Y}_{j} \left(  \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_{j}(\mathbf{X}(t_i))(t_{i+1}-t_{i}) \right)   \boldsymbol{\nu}_{j} $$ where $\boldsymbol{\nu}_{j}$ are state change vectors and by $t_{k}$ I mean the time at step $k$.